# The intersection of a collection of closed subsets of a compact metric space is nonempty

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $D$ be a collection of closed subsets of $X$ such that for every finite subcollection $E_1,...,E_n \in D, E_1 \cap...\cap E_n \not= \emptyset$. Prove that $\bigcap D \not= \emptyset$.

Am I essentially proving that $D$ is connected?

Would contradiction be the best way to go about proving this?

Comment: No, you are essentially proving that $X$ is compact. This is basically the definition of compactness, except that it is reformulated in terms of closed sets rather than open sets, and the contrapositive is taken.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property , do you know closed subsets of a compact metric space are compact?